# how to do the translations for custom buttons?

Tags: custom-button, translation

I want to translate my custom button label according to the country ( Totally 10 countries are there ). I know that standard button label cannot be renamed. My custom button name is " Send to MyManager".

Please help me out and thanks in advance !!

Comment: Use translation workbench and the appropriate $Label on your buttons maybe

Answer (score -2, accepted):

---

Hi,

Please refer the following article:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004527&language=en_US

Solution:

You need to go through the translation workbench:
Setup | Translation Workbench | Translate
Language = XXXX
Setup Component = Custom Field
Object = XXXX
Aspect =Related List Label

There are 2 columns, 1 for master list label and one for it's translation. You should double click in the translation column where the custom field label has the value Account, type your translated text and save.

---

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through the **translation workbench**:

1. Setup | Translation Workbench | Translate
2. Language = XXXX
3. Setup Component = Button and Link Label
4. Object = XXXX
5. Enable button to translate